# React - setTimeout() method not firing after Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have an arrow function that is invoked from `cDM` to retrieve the updated status of schedules every 20 seconds with a `setTimeout()`. The `setTimeout()` method never fires another request to the server like it's supposed to. So I'm thinking the code is never reached. I'm not sure exactly how to modify it so the method is reached.

```
componentDidMount() {
    //get request to /schedules
    //update state with response data
    this.getUpdatedStatus();
}

  getUpdatedStatus = () => {
    //fetch updated status,
    //list of arrays that are updated to state in `cDM`
    const schedules = this.state.schedules;
    Promise.all(
      schedules
        .map(schedule =>
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: schedule.selfUri,
            headers: {
              Accept: " someValue"
            }
          })
        )
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.data[0].status !== "Complete") {
            this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.getUpdatedStatus(), 20000);
          }
          console.log(response);
          this.setState(
            {
              scheduleStatus: response.data.data[0].status,
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state.scheduleStatus);
            }
          );
        })
    ).catch(error => console.log(error.response));
  };
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqy7w8k5qq)

Comment: `setTimeout` only fires once, you need `setInterval` to keep firing repeatedly

Comment: Promise.all() is used only with Promises, are you sure that your schedule.map is returning a promise? try encapsulating everything in a new Promise({code})

Comment: @duxfox-- `setTimeout` will keep (should) firing until my condition is met, I have this implemented elsewhere and works as expected.

Comment: Promise.all returns an array with the results. Maybe you want to iterate through them and do what you want to do?

Comment: Are you sure `response.data.data[0].status !== "Complete"`, Promise.all  will be return a array what all promises results by order, this mean `response ` (in `.then(response => ` stage) is a Array, not a json object. You maybe get a error like `cannot get xxx of undefined` in your console log.

Comment: @hoangdv I don't think it is returning an array, so this is the issue. I have a codesandbox that can reproduce the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/oqy7w8k5qq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in simple words, you are using wrong the `Promise.all()`, this is because the structure is something like:

`Promise.all([p1, p2,...,pn]).then([r1, r2, ..., rn])`

but your code is something like:
`Promise.all([p1, p2,...,pn].then(r))`

so basically your promise.all should be changed to something like this:

```
  getUpdatedStatus = () => {
    //fetch updated status,
    //list of arrays that are updated to state in `cDM`
    const schedules = this.state.schedules;
    Promise.all(
      schedules
        .map(schedule =>
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: schedule.selfUri,
            headers: {
              Accept: " someValue"
            }
          })
        ))
        .then(responses => {
          //now you have to iterate over the responses
          const isIncomplete = responses.some(r => r.data.data[0].status !== "Complete")
          if (isIncomplete) {
            this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.getUpdatedStatus(), 20000);
          }
          console.log(responses);
          this.setState(
            {
              scheduleStatus: isIncomplete?'Pending':'Complete',//improve this piece of code
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state.scheduleStatus);
            }
          );
        })
  };
```

here you have a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m50njvxj0p) with the code that you provided on your sandbox.

Comment: This is a good solution to my problem, thank you. I am noticing one slight problem, the `status` in the response object is coming back as `Complete` after about a minute or so (as expected), but the updated status is not being rendered correctly to the table itself, any ideas?

Comment: yes, I think if you are displaying a table with each status, you can rely on `this.state.scheduleStatus` because this will be true (thus, pending) if any of the responses is not completed. it will display completed only when everything is completed.

Comment: That's what I thought, doesn't seem to be re-rendering the updated status when it comes back `Complete` though.

Comment: do they all of them come back as completed? ie. response is [p, p, c, p] (p= pending, c=completed)
it will end up rendering Pending because it will be the last state that you set.... also, you are not saving the `responses` as the new updated schedule Array.

Comment: At the moment, the status stays pending, and continues to poll the server even though in the response object `status = Complete`

Comment: If I refresh the page is updates of course, so `this.state.scheduleStatus` isn't updating with the current value. And If I create more than one schedule, it will show the `status = completed` even though it is still pending.

Comment: as I asked before, do all the elements come back as completed? if one of them is still pending..... the status will keep in pending

Comment: Well since there's only currently one schedule I've sent to server, it stays pending no matter what the response object sends back.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the status being updated. There is a single schedule that in the response object is coming back with `completed` status after a few `timeout` callbacks. However, the updated status value is not re-rendering in the table. I believe setTimeout is asynchronous and I'm not saying to do anything with it when it completes

Comment: well, I would need the Render method from your component, maybe the change is being triggered, the problem could be another different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically @PrinceHernandez found the main issue, but there were a lot of other problems with your code:

- input field was read only
- missing `tbody`
- missing `key` attribute on each `tr`

I took the liberty to polish as I could, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vyk48x18n

Open console and you will see that the code updates every 2s printing `1`. Moving thenable to each schedule made necessary to have a flag controlling ONE invocation of timeout per `getUpdatedStatus`.

Comment: The `Query Name:` box is in fact readonly, this is identifying information I'm displaying to the user. This is just a codesandbox I threw together to paint an overall picture and to find the main issue with the `setTimeout()` method not being reached. Thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: Also only the outermost element that you return in `map` needs a key, not necessarily each individual element

Comment: ....... it was a React warning that stated that, man. I thought your problem were solved.